# LINQ TO SQL DATASOURCE cannot be dragged onto Windows Form c# VS 2012

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Using C#, SQL Server and LINQ to SQL Classes, I am trying to follow the tutorial below:

**How to:**  Create LINQ to SQL Classes Mapped to Tables and Views (O/R Designer)

on MSDN **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384396(v=vs.110).aspx.**

I am using Visual Studio 2012. The first issue is that there is no 'Data Menu', but I resolved that, you can get to the Data Window via View/Other Windows/Datasources, however, when actually trying to drag my table from the LINQ to SQL datasource onto a form I get the following error...

An error occurred while performing the drop.

```
BindingSource unable to create list on the Type specified in the DataSource Property.
```

Google has little to say on the subject. I found someone saying it was an IDE bug. Any other ideas?

Thank you.